# Fix compiler error with ; expected always etc

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i really need help fixing this and i don't know how to fix this
code

```
namespace ns0
{
using System;
using UnityEngine;

public sealed class GClass2
{
    private static System.Random random_0 = new System.Random();
    private static string string_0 = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";

    public static string smethod_0(int int_0, int int_1)
    {
        string str = "";
        int num = random_0.Next(int_0, int_1);
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        {
            int index = random_0.Next(string_0.Length - 1);
            str = str + string_0.ToCharArray()[index];
        }
        return str;
    }

    public static Texture2D smethod_1(float float_0, float float_1, float float_2, float float_3)
    {
        Texture2D textured = new Texture2D(1, 1);
        textured.SetPixel(0, 0, new Color(float_0, float_1, float_2, float_3));
        textured.Apply();
        return textured;
    }

    public static Vector3 smethod_2(Vector3 vector3_0, Vector3 vector3_1, Quaternion quaternion_0) =>
        (((Vector3) (quaternion_0 * (vector3_0 - vector3_1))) + vector3_1);
}
}
```

error is at line

```
public static Vector3 smethod_2(Vector3 vector3_0, Vector3 vector3_1, Quaternion quaternion_0) =>
    (((Vector3) (quaternion_0 * (vector3_0 - vector3_1))) + vector3_1);
```

where => character is then there is always ; expected error
and here is other errors

> Error 12  The type or namespace name 'vector3_1' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\user\Desktop\spoofid1\MonoInjector\GClass21.cs 32  54  managed

there is vector3_0 and vector3_1 and quaternion_0 could not be found
also

> Invalid token ')' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
>   Same error but with '-' and '('

Comment: Unity does not work with C# 6.0+, You have to redo your method to not use lambda expression.

Comment: **Expression-bodied function members** are a new feature that was introduced with C# 6.0. Try rewriting `smethod_2` as a regular method. **edit:** What he said.

Comment: edited it to 'public static Vector3 smethod_2(Vector3 vector3_0, Vector3 vector3_1, Quaternion quaternion_0)
{
 return quaternion_0 * (vector3_0 - vector3_1) + vector3_1;
}' and problem fixed

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use C# 6.0 in Unity project unless you will use third-party plugin https://bitbucket.org/alexzzzz/unity-c-5.0-and-6.0-integration/src

Quote from link above:

> Can I use C# 5/6/7 in Unity?
>
> Yes, you can.
>
> Unity has been stuck with CLR 2.0 for a very long time, but almost all the latest C# features do not require the latest versions of CLR. Microsoft and Mono compilers can compile C# 5/6/7 code for CLR 2.0 if you explicitly ask them to do so.
> Late binding (dynamic) feature that came with C# 4.0 still won't be available in Unity.

For your code to work in C# 3 you need to change method smethod_2

```
public static Vector3 smethod_2(Vector3 vector3_0, Vector3 vector3_1, Quaternion quaternion_0) 
{ 
    return (((Vector3) (quaternion_0 * (vector3_0 - vector3_1))) + vector3_1);
}
```